# Keycloak: Error deploying project with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, keycloak

I just downloaded the version 1.8 of Keycloak (the version called Demo), containing some projects already done on a JBoss application server that should be easily tested.

I installed the product and I'm able to access to it.

I checked the pre-requirements:

- java -version > 1.8.0_65 (1.8.* needed)
- mvn -version > 3.10.0 (3.2.1 needed)
- git --version > Installed

Just following the tutorial in YouTube ("Keycloak Tutorial: The Basics Part 2"), when I enter in the directory where is present the `pom.xml` file, I launch "mvn jboss-as:deploy", but the JBoss showes me this error:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Examples ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.093 s]
    [INFO] Customer Portal - Secured via Valve ................ FAILURE [  6.766 s]
    [INFO] Customer Portal CLI ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Customer Portal JS ................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Product Portal ..................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] EAR example ........................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Admin Access Example ............................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Angular Product Portal JS .......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] JAX-RS Database Service Using OAuth Bearer Tokens .. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Simple OAuth Client ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Simple OAuth Client Using CDI and JSF .............. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Service Account Example App ........................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Offline Access Portal .............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 10.568 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-15T00:35:37+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 34M/168M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.5.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project customer-portal-example: Could not execute goal deploy on /home/user/keycloak-demo-1.8.0.CR1/examples/unconfigured-demo/customer-app/target/customer-portal.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
    [ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
    [ERROR] "address" => [],
    [ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
    [ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :customer-portal-example
```

How should I address this error?

Comment: I believe you are following these examples https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/demo-template - did you choose the EAP6/AS7 route or the Wildfly route?

Comment: Hello Ahus,
I just unpacked the Keycloak and I did the checks about maven, java and git.
Probably the error could be the one mentioned by you, what should I do to fix the problem and go forward?
Thanks!!!!